# How to configure PuTTY + gpg-agent to connect an SSH Linux server

Tags: putty, gnupg, gpg-agent

I have a key-pair generated with Kleopatra (from Gpg4win 3.0 suite). I've converted the public key to an RSA ssh key and add it to the authorized_keys file in a Linux box.

On the Windows machine I've configured the `gpg-agent.conf` file as:

```
enable-putty-support
debug-level guru
log-file C:/Users/myusername/log.txt
disable-scdaemon
```

However, when I open PuTTY and try to connect to the server, I've got the error:

```
"Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)"
```

The question is: how can I use Putty from the Windows machine to connect to the Linux machine through SSH using the gpg key pair? I understood that gpg-agent impersonates `Pageant`agent so it should use the gpg private key on memory to serve encrypted strings to PuTTY. Is this right? or Am I misunderstanding everything here?.

Comment: Is the key whitelisted as a SSH key in gpg-agent (.gnupg/sshcontrol)?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the issue: complete working procedure at https://gist.github.com/matusnovak/302c7b003043849337f94518a71df777

As @user1686 said, it seems the only required step the OP hasn't done is to add the keygrip in the `sshcontrol` file.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the procedure that worked to integrate gpg with Putty is [here](https://occamy.chemistry.jhu.edu/references/pubsoft/YubikeySSH/index.php)

Looking at OP, it seems that is **missing the restart of the agent after** creating/modifying the `gpg-agent.conf` file:

```
gpg-connect-agent KILLAGENT /bye
```